# When linking against poco, get RegularExpression error

Tags: osx-mavericks, poco-libraries, gcc4.9

I have tried building poco (poco-1.4.6p4) in several ways, all seem to build fine. However, when linking against it, all the different ways I have tried to build poco give error below. No matter what I choose, it appears that poco is being built with the clang++.

What is strange is that before I upgraded from Mountain Lion to Mavericks, none of this happened.

```
./configure --Darwin64 --shared
```

and

```
./configure --Darwin64-gcc --shared --no-tests
```

and

```
./configure --Darwin64-clang-libc++ --shared --no-tests
```

All the above seem to build fine.

But when I link against any of them, they all give the error below when linking against it.

```
Making all in compiler
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++  -g -O2 -Wall -lfix8 -lPocoFoundation -lPocoNet -lPocoUtil  -L../runtime     -lz  -o f8c f8c.o f8cutils.o f8precomp.o  
libtool: link: g++ -g -O2 -Wall -o .libs/f8c f8c.o f8cutils.o f8precomp.o -Wl,-bind_at_load  /Users/ivanfigueredo/Downloads/fix8/runtime/.libs/libfix8.dylib -lpthread -lPocoFoundation -lPocoNet -lPocoUtil -L../runtime -lz
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Poco::RegularExpression::RegularExpression(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int, bool)", referenced from:
      FIX8::RegExp::RegExp(char const*, int) in f8c.o
  "Poco::RegularExpression::match(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned long, std::vector<Poco::RegularExpression::Match, std::allocator<Poco::RegularExpression::Match> >&, int) const", referenced from:
      _main in f8c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [f8c] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: g++ is notorious for the order of -l entries mattering.  Functions generally have to be used before they are defined.  Another possibility is that some functions were removed from poco and what you are trying to build has never been successfully built with those libraries.  You haven't given up on the Mac I see.  :)

Comment: Another thing is that name mangers differ between versions of c++ compilers.  Name mangers allow you to overload functions with different arguments but have the same name.  It's important to use the same compiler when using a library that you used to build the library itsrlf.

Comment: Manglers not manger on the mobile app.

Comment: I thought it might have to do with this, but I am unsure   https://trac.macports.org/ticket/41588 That seems to crash at runtime though not a compile-time error.

Comment: You are very close... did you make clean between your configure calls?

Comment: That page outlines why you cannot mix binaries and libraries with different compilers.

Comment: Yes, nothing helps :( But that is a __runtime__ error. I get a compile time error???!!!??

Comment: The article makes some suggestion to unify which compiler to use.

Comment: In the morning I will ponder.  Does this have to be on Mac?

Comment: Try this find g++ and name it g++.old

Comment: Then copy clang++ to g++

Comment: Try your compile and put it back

Comment: LOL! I was about to do the same thing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure generally will pay attention to CC and CXX environment variables to allow you to change compilers the software will build with.  Try and adjust these settings.

Comment: You beat me to it. This works. I can't believe that Apple broke compatibility with gcc ::eek::